# How to identify whether left drawer is open or right drawer is open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have map on right drawer and some other components on left drawer. I want to load some data to map when ONLY right drawer is opened. Can come one help me how to detect which drawer is open, left or right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
//load map data
}
```